# Parsing 300,000 Json objects per request.

Tags: javascript, json

I have an application idea and Im new to programming in javascript, node, angular. I am going to be using Big Oven's Api to parse through 300,000 recipes to return a group of recipes that I would use with each request. I know it would be a lot better if I had this data on my own local db as I could do this parsing, say once per hour and update the objects as needed. Should I pay the 100 dollars per month and spend the 15 days to request each recipe (at 1000 request limit per hour) until I have them all, or use some kind of http request that allows me access to all the objects somehow without maxing out my api request limit? Im just looking for a general Idea as to what methods I can use to overcome the api limits and time per request issues.

Comment: This completely depends on how the API works, How protected is the API in means of authentication , I dont think there is much you can do about it with just having the API url...

Answer (score 2):

Read [Terms of Use](http://api2.bigoven.com/web/documentation/termsofuse).

> You may present BigOven Data only on a transactional basis. You are not permitted to store (or "cache") BigOven Data locally unless specifically negotiated and approved in writing by us.
>
> [...]
>
> You may not use the BigOven APIs in a manner that exceeds reasonable request volume, constitutes excessive or abusive usage, or otherwise fails to comply or is inconsistent with any part of the BigOven API documentation located within http://api.bigoven.com/, as determined by BigOven in its sole discretion.

Your challenge is not merely technical, but legal. If you don't like it, the only (legal) recourse for you is to ask Big Oven if they will make a concession for you. It may end up costing considerably more than $100.